# Pass textbox values from view to ViewComponent

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a view which calls a view component  and passes a model called Konstant in the following way:

```
@foreach (Konstant item in Model)
{
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="@item.KANAL" class="tab-pane fade in">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("MeterReader2", new { k = item })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

If we look at the ViewComponent, it looks like this:

```
public class MeterReader2ViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(Models.Konstant k) 
    // Endast en kanal.
    { 
     // logic.... 
    }
}
```

So far, this works for me. My question however is, how do I introduce two textboxes in the view which should include start and end date fields, where the inputed values should be sent to the view component?

I was thinking something like:

```
<input type="text" id="startDate", name="start" value="" />
<input type="text" id="endDate", name="end" value="" />
```

And then:

```
@foreach (Konstant item in Model)
{
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="@item.KANAL" class="tab-pane fade in">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("MeterReader2", new { k = item, start = startDate, end = endDate })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Lastly, within the View Component itself: include the parameters:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(Models.Konstant k, string start, string end) // Endast en kanal.
{ 
  // logic.... 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the model as IEnumerable, I'd recommend creating:

```
public class KonstantViewModel
{
   public List<Konstant> Konstants { get; set; }

   public string start { get; set; }

   public string end { get; set; }
}
```

Since the name of your inputs are start and end, named inputs will postback and map to the start and end properties in this model (You could also use NameFor extension to explicitly map if you like too).  So on postback, the model will receive the start/end, and then you can pass these model properties to the view component.

The problem you are having is you need a middle man to pass the values.  This solution expects that you need to get the values and pass them in during a postback scenario.  If you were expecting that to happen on the client, then a JavaScript solution is needed.

Comment: How would such a JavaScript look like @Brian Mains?

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954683/asp-net-core-mvc-with-view-component-not-detecting-returning-ajax-request-on-2nd

Comment: I normally use a controller action, which would return whatever is needed (for me partial views since I'm still on MVC 5): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559515/jquery-ajax-call-to-controller

Comment: I am still stuck on this issue. Do you feel like helping me directly? @Brian Mains ? I have downloaded Knockout JS to bind some data models. Can´t get it to work properly though...

Answer (score 0):

you can add to ViewData and then get it in your view like this

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(Models.Konstant k, string start, string end)
{
     ViewData["startDate"] = start;
     ViewData["endDate"] = end;
     rest of your logic here ...
}

<input type="text" id="startDate", name="start" value="@ViewData["startDate"]" />
<input type="text" id="endDate", name="end" value="@ViewData["endDate"]" />
```